# Maximum value of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find the maximum value of the modulus of the complex polynomial $$p(z)=5z^4+e^{\frac{i5\pi}{6}}z^3+e^{\frac{i5\pi}{6}}z+5$$ on $|z|=1.$
I think maximum occurs at $z=1$ and hence
$$\max_{|z|=1}|p(z)|=|10+2e^{\frac{i5\pi}{6}}|.$$
Am I right?

Comment: Why do you think that the maximum is attained when $z=1$?

Comment: The real part of $e^{i\frac56 \pi}$ is negative, $|p(z)|$ is maximized at $z = -1$ instead of $1$.

Comment: No polynomial has a maximum value on such a domain as $\mathbf C,$ or over what subdomain of $\mathbf C$ are you considering this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that unit circle $|z|=1$ is described by $z=e^{i\phi}$ for $\phi\in[0,2\pi]$.
Thus,
$$
\max_{|z|=1} |p(z)| = \max_{\phi\in[0,2\pi]} \left|p(e^{i\phi})\right| \,.
$$
Next, note that the maxima of the absolute value is attained at the same $\phi$ as for the absolute value squared
$$
\underset{\phi\in[0,2\pi]}{\operatorname{arg\,max}} \left|p(e^{i\phi})\right|
= \underset{\phi\in[0,2\pi]}{\operatorname{arg\,max}} \left|p(e^{i\phi})\right|^2 \,.
$$
Insertion yields
$$
\begin{align}
p(e^{i\phi})
&= 5(1+e^{i4\phi}) + e^{i( \frac{5}{6} \pi+\phi)} (1+e^{i2\phi})
\\
\implies \left|p(e^{i\phi})\right|^2
&= p(e^{i\phi}) p(e^{i\phi})^* 
\\
&= 50\left(1+\cos(4\phi)\right) + 2\left(1+\cos(2\phi)\right) 
\\
& \qquad+ 10 \left(
\cos(\frac{5}{6} \pi+\phi)+\cos(\frac{5}{6} \pi-\phi)+\cos(\frac{5}{6} \pi+3\phi)+\cos(\frac{5}{6} \pi-3\phi)
\right) 
\\
&= 50\left(1+\cos(4\phi)\right) + 2\left(1+\cos(2\phi)\right) 
\\
& \qquad+ 20 \cos(\frac{5}{6} \pi) \left(
\cos(\phi)+\cos(3\phi)
\right) 
\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^4 c_j \cos(j \phi)
\,.
\end{align} 
$$
Maxima can be found at $\phi=\pi$ which gives $z=-1$.

---

Edit: Changed 2nd equation as indicated by Brian Moehring's comment.

Comment: Is there any computational software to find the maximum of polynomials on a unit circle?

Comment: I think you mean either  $$\underset{\phi\in[0,2\pi]}{\operatorname{arg max}} \left|p(e^{i\phi})\right| 
= \underset{\phi\in[0,2\pi]}{\operatorname{arg max}} \left|p(e^{i\phi})\right|^2$$ or maybe $$\max_{\phi\in[0,2\pi]} \left|p(e^{i\phi})\right| 
= \sqrt{\max_{\phi\in[0,2\pi]} \left|p(e^{i\phi})\right|^2}$$

Both are true, but it sounds like you're using the former for the rest of your solution.